# Como fazer requisição GET/POST com Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, rest, post, restful, get

Preciso fazer uma requisição tanto post como get de uma REST API, queria saber como fazer a requisição com Node.js?

Encontrei alguns artigos na internet mas nada sucinto.

Comment: Aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321/how-to-make-remote-rest-call-inside-node-js-any-curl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) têm uma API nativa para HTTP, [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), que funciona assim:

```js
var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST', // <--- aqui podes escolher o método
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let data = '';
  res.on('data', d => data += d);
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Terminado! Data:', data);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`Houve um erro: ${e.message}`);
});

// aqui podes enviar data no POST
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

A resposta pode ser usada dentro de `res.on('end', () => {`.

Existem bibliotecas que simplificam isto, uma delas é o [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Nesse caso a API pode ser assim:

```js
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Aqui podes ver o HTML da página pedida. 
  }
})
```

Comment: O código não ganhou destaque de sintaxe, que estranho. É javascript isso?

Comment: @diegofm sim, é JavaScript, estranho. Vou juntar as tags.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a maneira mais fácil de fazer requisições é com o Request
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Além desse meio com callbacks você pode usar promises e async/await.